# As I am new to embedded programming I am not able to understand what is "%s\xC2\xB0" ? I know %s is for string

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-fonts

```
(void)sprintf(Thermo_Buff,"%s\xC2\xB0""",a); //to add to buffer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In string literals, a backslash `\` is used as a prefix for special characters. I'm sure you know about newline (`"\n"`) for example.

If the special character after the backslash is an `x` then it means that the next two characters are hexadecimal digits, and those two digits are the translated by the compiler into a character.

In your example the `sprintf` call adds a string, and then two separate characters based on the hexadecimal numbers `0xc2` and `0xb0`, which is UTF-8 for a degree character (see e.g. [this reference](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=176&htmlent=1)).

Answer (score 1):

That's a degree sign, encoded as UTF-8 unicode.

You can have a look at a more complete list of characters and what they look like in UTF-8 [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex).

Answer (score 0):

In C, something in the format `\x???` in a string literal, where `???` are numbers, is a *Unicode escape*.  It is a way of entering Unicode characters which cannot be entered with a keyboard.  In this case, if you look at [this table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), you will see that the escape sequence `c2 b0` (written `\xC2\xB0` in your code encodes a **degree sign** - so that is what this means.